# Why doesn't inserting a fragment in index.html

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The app is based on Spring-Boot + thymeleaf. The file starts first index.html, which is located in the static folder. All other templates are located in the templates folder. I was thinking of doing index.html the main page of the site. But I'm trying to insert a fragment of the header there using thymeleaf, and nothing works, i.e. this fragment is not on this page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:insert="navbar :: f-navbar"></div>
    <p>Go: <a href="/setting">Настройки</a></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

And if I go to the setting page, where exactly the same fragment is displayed perfectly. What am I doing wrong?
Or is it not allowed to do this in this file?
Then why do you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `static` folder is served by Spring Boot as is. There is no Thymeleaf processing going on there. Move your `index.html` inside the `templates` folder as well.

If that is not enough to make it work, you can add a simple `RootController`:

```
public class RootController {
  @GetMapping("/")
  public String homePage() {
    return "index"
  }
}
```